# ¿Hay algún criterio de ordenación de las acepciones en el Diccionario de la Lengua?

Tags: rae, dle

Recién acabo de consultar el vocablo [**grifo / fa**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JXWzD27) en el Diccionario de la Lengua Española y he hallado:

> 1. Dicho del cabello: Crespo o enmarañado.
> 2. Dicho de una persona: De pelo ensortijado que indica mezcla de las razas blanca y negra.
> 3. Entonado, presuntuoso.
> 4. Dicho de una persona: Intoxicada con marihuana.
> 5. Dicho de una persona: Que tiene la carne de gallina.
> 6. Dicho de un ave, y especialmente de un gallo o de una gallina: Que tiene las plumas encrespadas.
> 7. ebrio (‖ embriagado por la bebida).
> 8. Animal fabuloso, de medio cuerpo arriba águila, y de medio abajo león.
> 9. Llave colocada en la boca de las cañerías, en depósitos de líquidos, etc., a fin de regular el paso de estos.
> 10. Surtidor de gasolina, gasóleo o queroseno.
> 11. llave grifa.
> 12. cáñamo índico.

De todas estas las más conocidas para mi son la (8) y (9) - de hecho, cuando pienso en un *grifo*, pienso automáticamente en la acepción (9) y no en ninguna de las otras.
Me ha llamado la atención que esa acepción esté tan "enterrada", lo que me ha hecho especular si hay algún criterio para el orden en que aparecen las acepciones (supongo que si) y cuál será este.

Comment: No lo sé con certeza pero fíjate que primero van los adjetivos (1-7) y luego los sustantivos (8-12). Probablemente van por ahí los tiros.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Efectivamente, aquí lo explica la RAE: [RAE - Orden en las acepciones](http://www.rae.es/publicaciones/53-acepciones).

Primero por **categoría** y subcategoría **gramatical**.

Y dentro de las categorías gramaticales, por **marcas**: sin  marcas, niveles de lengua, técnica, geográficas, etc.

En el artículo viene explicado con todo lujo de detalles.

Comment: Y además aclara que puede haber excepciones, ilustrándolo con ejemplos. Magnifico!